I want to configure AWS s3 bucket with my wordpress plugin
Here is my example plugin for AWS S3 configuration
Here is my php my-s3-plugin.php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My S3 Plugin
Description: A plugin to integrate AWS S3 with WordPress.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

function pda_s3_integration_update_general_setting() {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    // Security check
    $nonce = $_REQUEST['security_check'];
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'pdas3_ajax_nonce')) {
        error_log('Nonce verification failed', 0);
        wp_die('invalid_nonce');
    }

    // Get settings from request
    $settings = $_REQUEST['settings'];
    if (empty($settings)) {
        error_log('Settings are empty', 0);
        wp_die('Settings are empty');
    }

    // Assign settings to variables
    $region = $settings["region"] ?? null;
    $accessKeyId = $settings["aws_key"] ?? null;
    $secretAccessKey = $settings["aws_secret"] ?? null;
    $bucketName = $settings["bucket"] ?? null;

    // Log and verify settings
    if (!$region || !$accessKeyId || !$secretAccessKey || !$bucketName) {
        error_log("Region: $region, Access Key ID: $accessKeyId, Secret Access Key: $secretAccessKey, Bucket Name: $bucketName", 0);
        wp_die('Invalid AWS configuration settings');
    }

    // Initialize S3 client and check bucket
    try {
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => $region,
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $accessKeyId,
                'secret' => $secretAccessKey,
            ],
        ]);

        $isOk = $s3Client->doesBucketExist($bucketName);

        if (!$isOk) {
            wp_send_json($isOk);
            wp_die();
        }

    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        error_log('AWS Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);
        wp_die('AWS SDK error');
    }
}

// Hook into WordPress admin to add your function
add_action('wp_ajax_pda_s3_integration_update_general_setting', 'pda_s3_integration_update_general_setting');

// Enqueue the JavaScript file
function my_s3_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-s3-plugin-js', plugins_url('js/my-s3-plugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    // Localize the script with new data
    wp_localize_script('my-s3-plugin-js', 'myS3Plugin', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('pdas3_ajax_nonce')
    ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_s3_plugin_enqueue_scripts');

Here is my js file
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'pda_s3_integration_update_general_setting',
        security_check: myS3Plugin.nonce,
        settings: {
            region: 'EXAMPLE',
            aws_key: 'EXAMPLE',
            aws_secret: 'EXAMPLE',
            bucket: 'EXAMPLE'
        }
    };

    $.post(myS3Plugin.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});

Here is my composer.json file
{
    "require": {
      "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.318",
        "coenjacobs/mozart": "^0.7.1"
    }
}

I want to configure AWS s3 bucket with the latest version 3.318.0
Here is the errors I am getting
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_default_ignore_configured_endpoint_urls(): Argument #1 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_ignore_configured_endpoint_urls(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_default_endpoint(): Argument #1 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "ignore_configured_endpoint_urls" in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php</b> on line <b>1245</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_endpoint(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_region(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\S3\S3Client::_applyApiProvider(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_defaults(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_default_use_fips_endpoint(): Argument #1 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_use_fips_endpoint(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_default_use_dual_stack_endpoint(): Argument #1 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_use_dual_stack_endpoint(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Aws\ClientResolver::_apply_endpoint_provider(): Argument #2 ($args) must be passed by reference, value given in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php</b> on line <b>419</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "api" in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php</b> on line <b>1155</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: Aws\Api\Service::createSerializer(): Argument #1 ($api) must be of type Aws\Api\Service, null given, called in C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php on line 1154 and defined in C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Api\Service.php:83
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php(1154): Aws\Api\Service::createSerializer(NULL, '')
#1 [internal function]: Aws\ClientResolver::_default_serializer(Array)
#2 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\prevent-direct-access-gold-3.0\vendor\antecedent\patchwork\src\CallRerouting.php(419): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php(393): Patchwork\CallRerouting\dispatchDynamic(Array, Array)
#4 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\AwsClient.php(248): Aws\ClientResolver-&gt;resolve(Array, Object(Aws\HandlerList))
#5 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3\S3Client.php(381): Aws\AwsClient-&gt;__construct(Array)
#6 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\my-s3-plugin.php(47): Aws\S3\S3Client-&gt;__construct(Array)
#7 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): pda_s3_integration_update_general_setting('')
#8 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters('', Array)
#9 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array)
#10 C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php(192): do_action('wp_ajax_pda_s3_...')
#11 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Users\Meet\Local Sites\pda-live\app\public\wp-content\plugins\my-s3-plugin\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Api\Service.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p><p><a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-troubleshooting/">Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a></p> 

Here is the snapshot of errors and warning I am getting
enter image description here
